# post data-id using ajax form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've a question about ajax form. So, You can see my following ajax code have `data-id` . I'm getting this id in `.pmsc` div. But When I press **#upmsc** for uploading image then I am not getting any error, just getting this result from chrome developer console, no upload, no inserting the image name in database. What I'm doing wrong here.

[image]

Then ajax submit form is this

```
$('body').on('change', '#upmsc', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var id = $(".pmsc").attr("data-id");
   var data = 'id=' + id;
   $("#musicform").ajaxForm({
      type: "POST",
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      target: '.appended',
      beforeSubmit: function() {
         // Do Something
      },
      success: function(response) {
         // Do Something
         $(".showecho").html(response);
      },
      error: function() {}
   }).submit();
});
```

My html form is this:

```
    <form id="cfrm" class="options-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'.$base_url.'upload.php">
       <label class="mcup" for="upcmsc"></label>
<input type="file" name="musicCover" id="upcmsc" />
    </form>
    <div class="pmsc" id="56">
    </div>
```

and PHP code is this

```
<?php
include_once 'inc/inc.php';
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg","PNG","JPG","JPEG","GIF","BMP");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['id']);
    $name = $_FILES['musicCover']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['musicCover']['size'];
    if(strlen($name)) {
        $ext = getExtension($name);
        if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)) {
            if($size<(50024*50024)) { 
                $actual_image_name = time().$uid.".".$ext;
                $tmp = $_FILES['musicCover']['tmp_name'];
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $mcoverpath.$actual_image_name)) {
                    $data=$HuHu->Music_Cover_Image_Upload($id,$actual_image_name);
                    if($data){
                        echo '<img class="cover covermsc" src="'.$base_url.$mcoverpath.$actual_image_name.'">';
                        }
                  } else {
                      echo "Fail upload folder with read access.";
                }
                } else
                  echo "Image file size max 1 MB";                  
       } else
          echo "Invalid file format.";
     } else
         echo "Please select image..!";
        exit;
 }


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = 'id=' + id;
$("#musicform").ajaxForm({
  type: "POST",
  data: data,
```

You set the additional data to a string while it should be an object. That then fails your checks in the PHP code. So try this:

```
var data = {id: id};
```

Found some more problems with the PHP code braces, try this:

```
<?php
include_once 'inc/inc.php';
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg","PNG","JPG","JPEG","GIF","BMP");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['id']);
    $name = $_FILES['musicCover']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['musicCover']['size'];

    if(strlen($name)) {
        $ext = getExtension($name);
        if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)) {
            if($size<(50024*50024)) { 
                $actual_image_name = time().$uid.".".$ext;
                $tmp = $_FILES['musicCover']['tmp_name'];

                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $mcoverpath.$actual_image_name)) {
                    $data=$HuHu->Music_Cover_Image_Upload($id,$actual_image_name);
                    if($newdata){
                        echo '<img class="cover covermsc" src="'.$base_url.$mcoverpath.$actual_image_name.'">';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Fail upload folder with read access.";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Image file size max 1 MB";        
            }
        } else {
            echo "Invalid file format.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please select image..!";
        exit;
    }
} else {
    echo '1';   
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. Now i am getting `Please select a image` error.

Comment: Can you check how the request that is sent looks like? Seems like the file is not transferred correctly.

Comment: the new request developer console looks like this: [Please click for screen](https://scontent-lht6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17903939_446922572307574_6487297277092758268_n.jpg?oh=6b86b06afc239f5a7e88b8f4b28a7494&oe=599AF6F4)

Comment: Ok and how does a var_dump of $_FILES look like?

Comment: That is definitely not the output of $_FILES... Maybe `$_FILES['musicCover']['name']`?

Comment: that output `$name = var_dump($_FILES['musicCover']['name']);`

Comment: right, ok, but if you remove the var_dump then the `if (strlen($name))` should definitely pass. So unless your code is different than the posted above, I don't see how you get the `Please select an image` error?

Comment: can you check the question php codes i will show you also where is it: please click this [screenshot](https://scontent-lht6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17952985_446930815640083_6051595787358220874_n.jpg?oh=875eda3d1e2810af9365c23b5e4fb431&oe=59514F90)

Comment: I know where it is, but if

`var_dump($_FILES['musicCover']['name'])` results in `string(9) "image.jpg"`

then

`$name = $_FILES['musicCover']['name'];`
`if(strlen($name)) {`
should be true as strlen($name) should then be 9...

Comment: Ok, I think you have some wrong braces, will update answer in a minute.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You saved my time.

Comment: just one more mini question how to append echo in a div now. I am trying to show after success like `$(".showecho").html(response);`